# Should We Change Upvoting Functionality for Comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, up-votes

If you upvote a comment and then try to remove the upvote, you get the following message:

> Are you sure you want to undo your upvote on this comment? You will not be able to upvote it again

And sure enough, when trying to upvote afterwards:

> [image]

What is the purpose of this feature? If I accidentally upvote a comment and decide to remove the upvote, I still want the ability to upvote it if I decide to do so later on.

When voting on questions and answers, you can toggle votes on and off as much as you want for at least 5 minutes, after which they lock. Even after a vote is locked, you can change the vote if the post is edited. **Why do comments, which hold much less data integrity value for the site, have more restrictions than questions and answers do?** It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken there are similar restrictions on up/down votes. I doubt this is a change that could be made without making it network wide.  If you feel really really strongly about it you could take it to meta.se.

Comment: Probably (*probably*) to avoid DOS attacks? I bet a lot of actions are limited in some fashion or another.

Comment: I suspect it is part of a parcel of features that are intended to discourage commenting. SE wants questions and answers, and any other stuff can go in a chatroom or other forum. Any requests to improve commenting features are unlikely to be successful.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the why: once upon a time, you couldn't retract your upvote at all. This ability was added later [mainly to help with mis-clicks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/160551) rather than as part of the full-fledged voting system posts use.  From the linked post:

> - You can un-upvote a comment within the first 60 seconds, provided you did not navigate away.
> - Once you un-upvote a comment you can not upvote it again.
>
> We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past. The only use case is undoing a mis-click.

The reduced functionality around comment voting is part of the broader pattern that comments are second-class citizens compared to questions or answers. [You can't even downvote a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/allow-downvoting-comments), much less edit one more than 5 minutes after posting.